# Delete a Row from a DataGridView given its index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce

My DataGridView is a single line selection and theres a rowEnter Event where I get the line index every time the selected line changes.

```
    private void rowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        currentRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

when I press a delete button I use the same index to delete the row

```
            myDataSet.Avaliado.Rows[currentRowIndex].Delete();
            avaliadoTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.Avaliado);
```

it works fine if no column in the DataGridView is sorted, otherwise a get an error. What should be the way to know the row index in the dataset that corresponds to the rowindex from the DataGridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be grabbing the current row index every time a new row is selected.  Try something like this instead:

```
if (_Grid.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) { return; } // nothing selected

DataGridViewRow dgvRow = _Grid.SelectedRows[0];

// assuming you have a DataTable bound to the DataGridView:
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dgvRow.DataBoundItem;
// now go about deleting the row however you would do that.
```

If you've got some other sort of data type bound to each row of the grid, simply cast the `DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` to whatever your data type is.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Just a comment. In the wurry you did a mistake. Nothing serious. :)
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dgvRow.DataBoundItem;
Only strange thing is that when the last row in the DGV is deleted, the DVG do not select the previous available row.

Comment: Oops!  You're correct.  The sample piece of code I was looking at for whipping up that sample code involved a BindingList<T> bound to a DataGridView, so there was no intermediary DataRowView.  I'll update the example...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the currently selected row at the time that you are doing the delete:

```
if(myDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
     currentRowIndex = myDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Comment: its the same value I already have from rowEnter event, isnt it? A row in a DataGridView has a index, a row of data in a dataset has another position that not necessarily corresponds to the the DataGridView. Thats the point.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you meant that you were losing the proper index when the column gets sorted. myDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem is indeed what you're interested in then.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have the Primary Key for that row as a hidden column (my convention is using the first using column).

I can then ask my persistence Layer to do the rest.